# Jordan Normal Form and Minimal Polynomial

Tags: jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Write down all possible Jordan normal
forms for matrices with characteristic polynomial$ (x − λ)^5$.

In each case, calculate the minimal polynomial and the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue λ.

For the only eigenvalue $\lambda$, the possible JNF is just assigned 1 to every column above the diagonal since the min polynomial can be any degree from 1 to 5?

I figured out the possible JNF using the possible minimal polynomial

$(x-\lambda)$and $(x-\lambda)^2$ and $(x-\lambda)^3$...$(x-\lambda)^5$
In total, it is 7 possibility (corresponding to each minimal polynomial and $\lambda$ has to appear 5 times.)
But I don't understand that why the number of blocks gives the geometric multiplicity since each represent one eigenspace.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They basically correspond to partitions of $5$. Take the diagonal matrix $\lambda I_5$ and then insert some ones onto the superdiagonal. Let $J_n$ denote the matrix

$$
J_n := 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda &&&& \\
1 & \lambda && \\
& 1 & \lambda && \\
&& & \ddots & \\
&&& 1 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $n$ lambdas. Then the possible Jordan forms are

- $J_1 \oplus J_1 \oplus J_1 \oplus J_1 \oplus J_1$
- $J_1 \oplus J_1 \oplus J_1 \oplus J_2$
- $J_1 \oplus J_2 \oplus J_2$
- $J_1 \oplus J_1 \oplus J_3$
- $J_2 \oplus J_3$
- $J_1 \oplus J_4$
- $J_5$

Try to figure out the minimal polynomial and geometric multiplicity on your own. If you need help:

> If $\mu = \mu_1 \le \mu_2 \le \dots \le \mu_k$ is a partition of $5$ with $k$ parts then the Jordan matrix corresponding to $\mu$ has minimal polynomial $(x - \lambda)^{\mu_k}$ (i.e. the exponent is the largest part of $\mu$). The geometric multiplicity is $k$.